# Why are there two different versions of how Luffy ate the Gum-Gum fruit?

Tags: one-piece, shonen-jump

I am watching "Romance Dawn", a fairly new episode of *One Piece*, but is just a different version of the original manga idea that was adapted into the first anime series (at least that’s my understanding). It shows Luffy snacking on a Gum-Gum fruit that his grandfather Garp brings home as treasure from a raid as a Peace pirate.

This made me think, and actually visualize a scene where I recalled him eating the fruit in a tavern with Shanks and a bunch of his crew, which I was able to confirm with a quick YouTube search.

So what is going on?

Answer (score 11):

Before One Piece became serialized in 1997, Oda wrote a **different version** of the first chapter of the series, entitled **Romance Dawn**, where things happen as per the latest episode, in which Garp is a pirate and feeds Luffy the *Gomu Gomu no Mi*. This is just a directorial decision to show how Oda envisioned the original start of the story prior to making the change as it is currently in the manga.

The first chapter that was published shows Shanks - the pirate - bring *Gomu Gomu no Mi* to Monkey D. Luffy's hometown and it is considered the true and intended version of the first chapter of One Piece and it keeps the intended name, **Romance Dawn**.